# Python Regex Scrape

Tags: python, regex, findall

I have this piece of code with prices from a product(the price and offer for installments)  and I try to scrape with python to get only the price(649).

```
<span style="color: #404040; font-size: 12px;"> from </span>
<span class="money-int">649</span>
<sup class="money-decimal">99</sup>
<span class="money-currency">$</span>
<br />
<span style="color: #404040; font-size: 12px;">from 
    <b>
        <span class="money-int">37</span>
        <sup class="money-decimal">35</sup>
        <span class="money-currency">$</span>/month
    </b>
</span>
```

I tried using `re.findall` like this

```
match = re.findall('\"money-int\"\>(\d*)\<\/span\>\<sup class=\"money-decimal\"\>(\d*)',content)
```

The problem is I get list with both prices, 649 and 37 and I need only 649.

Comment: `re.search(r'\"money-int\"\>(\d*)\<\/span\>\s*\<sup class=\"money-decimal\"\>(\d*)',content).group(1)`

Answer (score 0):

```
re.findall(r"<span[^>]*class=\"money-int\"[^>]*>([^<]*)</span>[^<]*<sup[^>]*class=\"money-decimal\"[^>]*>([^<]*)</sup>", YOUR_STRING)
```

Comment: Please add some more explanation to your answer, don't just drop a line of code.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using an xml parser to do this job to avoid future headaches:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS

html = '''
<span style="color: #404040; font-size: 12px;"> from </span>
<span class="money-int">649</span>
<sup class="money-decimal">99</sup>
<span class="money-currency">$</span>
<br />
<span style="color: #404040; font-size: 12px;">from
    <b>
        <span class="money-int">37</span>
        <sup class="money-decimal">35</sup>
        <span class="money-currency">$</span>/month
    </b>
</span>
'''

soup = BS(html, 'lxml')

print soup.find_all("span", attrs={"class": "money-int"})[0].get_text()
```

Online demo on [ideone](http://ideone.com/hd1W1C)